# ReactNative: Show a component or another page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a page in which I have a return like:

```
const MyPage1 = ({holiday, holidayStatus}) => {

// in Render I check some conditions to show or another component or a page:

const Render = () => {
 if ((holidayStatus === 'APPROVED' || holidayStatus === 'REJECTED' || holidayStatus === 'DELETED') && Object.keys(holiday).length > 0){
 return (
  <>
   <RenderDetail />
  </>
)}
else if  ((holidayStatus === 'WAITING' || holidayStatus === 'DRAFT') && Object.keys(holiday).length > 0) {
   return (
  <>
   <EditRequest holiday={holiday}/>
  </>
)}
else {
    return(
    <>
      <RenderSpinner />
   </>
   )
 }
  }

    return (
      <>
       <Render />
      </>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    holiday: state.holiday.holidayInfo,
    holidayStatus: state.holiday.holidayInfo.status,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getHolidayInfo: (payload) => dispatch(getHolidayInfo(payload)),
})
```

Where EditRequest is a newPage while RenderDetail is a component inside the same page.

Now my problem is that every time I change from RenderDetail  to EditRequest (or the same for the opposite) the application show for a second the RenderDetail and then show EditRequest.

In your opinion how can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by adding `switch` statement. Because first it checks the statement then execute.

But in `if/else` statement code check both if `if` is false first it check if then it goes to else

If you prefer to do with `if` statement the removes `else if` use only `if` statement it can resolve your issue.

As,

```
const MyPage1 = ({holiday, holidayStatus}) => {

 // in Render I check some conditions to show or another component or a page:

 const Render = () => {
  if ((holidayStatus === 'APPROVED' || holidayStatus === 'REJECTED' || holidayStatus === 'DELETED') && Object.keys(holiday).length > 0){
 return (
   <>
    <RenderDetail />
   </>
 )}
 if  ((holidayStatus === 'WAITING' || holidayStatus === 'DRAFT') && Object.keys(holiday).length > 0) {
    return (
   <>
    <EditRequest holiday={holiday}/>
   </>
 )}
 else {
     return(
     <>
       <RenderSpinner />
     </>
    )
  }
   }

     return (
       <>
        <Render />
       </>
     )
 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     holiday: state.holiday.holidayInfo,
     holidayStatus: state.holiday.holidayInfo.status,
   }
 }

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
   getHolidayInfo: (payload) => dispatch(getHolidayInfo(payload)),
 })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem still remains.. could be a problem about the holidayStatus from mapStateToProps that it doesn't change immediatly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the if's that you use, you must to consider to use switch in this case.

```
 const MyPage1 = ({ holiday, holidayStatus }) => {
  const Render = () => {
    if (Object.keys(holiday).length > 0) {
      switch (holidayStatus) {
        case 'APPROVED': case 'REJECTED': case 'DELETED':
          return <RenderDetail />
        case 'WAITING': case 'DRAFT':
          return <EditRequest holiday={holiday} />
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    return <RenderSpinner />
  }
  return <Render />
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    holiday: state.holiday.holidayInfo,
    holidayStatus: state.holiday.holidayInfo.status,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getHolidayInfo: (payload) => dispatch(getHolidayInfo(payload)),
})
```

The code looks cleaner too

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem still remains.. could be a problem about the holidayStatus from mapStateToProps that it doesn't change immediatly?